# Library to find out type of CPU and features

Tags: java, cpu

I want to know what type of CPU (Intel Pentium V, AMD Athlon Barton etc.) is built in and which features it has (SSE, MMX, Stepping etc.). Is there some ready-made Java-library for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows you could use [Jawin](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/jawin.html) to access the Win32 API.

Comment: I'm especially interested in a solution for Windows, GNU/Linux and FreeBSD.

Comment: I guess if your OS is GNU/Linux you could try to parse "/proc/cpuinfo".  If it is FreeBSD (or Linux) you could try to parse the output of "dmesg".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for Windows, the combination Jawin and WMI could be the solution. Here is a good [article](http://codegods.de/2008/03/26/windows-management-instrumentation-wmi-und-java). Unfortunately in German only, but maybe the example code helps.

Answer (score -1):

The JVM does this internally so you don't need to know.  There is no way in Java to take advantage of this information other than what the JVM does for you already.

Why do you want to know?

Comment: I want to load some special libraries based on CPU type.

Comment: Java can use SSE etc if the CPU has it but you need to know if the CPU supports it first

Comment: @qhi, You can't do think in pure Java because it would never be an issue. Since you are using JNI I suggest you use JNI to determine the CPU type. I suspect there is no OS-independent way to achieve this.